# Number format with commas and one decimal

Tags: python

I have a number with 1 decimal point such as `123456.1` i would like to format it to `123,456.1`

Tried to use locale to format the number but was unable to get it to work

Instead I used the following:

```
def format(n):
    r = []
    for i, c in enumerate(reversed(str(n))):
        if i and (not (i % 3)):
            r.insert(0, ',')
        r.insert(0, c)
    return ''.join(r)
```

which results in `1,234,56.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).

```
>>> '{:,}'.format(123456.1)
'123,456.1'
```